# pass a value from one page to another outside querystring and without javascript?

Tags: php

One solution to automatically building navigation for a site is by scanning a folder for documents like this:

```
foreach(glob('pages/*.pg.php') as $_SITE_NAV_filePath):
    $_SITE_NAV_filePath = explode('.pg',pathinfo($_SITE_NAV_filePath,PATHINFO_FILENAME));
    $_SITE_NAV_fileName = $_SITE_NAV_filePath[0];

    $_SITE_NAV_qv = preg_replace('/([A-Z])/','-$1',$_SITE_NAV_fileName);  $_SITE_NAV_qv = trim($_SITE_NAV_qv,'-');
    $_SITE_NAV_name = preg_replace('/([A-Z])/',' $1',$_SITE_NAV_fileName);
    ?>
    <li><a href="?page=<?=$_SITE_NAV_qv?>" class="<?=$_SITE_NAV_qv == $_SITE_PAGE['qv']?'active':''?>"><?=$_SITE_NAV_name?></a></li>
    <?php
endforeach;
```

This code will turn "AnAwesomePage.pg.php" into a menu item like this :
`<li><a href="?page=An-Awesome-Page">An Awesome Page</a></li>`

This might be bad practice (?).
Anyway; I don't use this method very often since most of the time the sites have a database, and with that comes better solutions...

**But my question is this:**
Is there a way to prefix the filename with a integer followed by and underscore *(3_AnAwesomePage.pg.php)*, for sorting order purposes, and pass it somehow to the destination page outside of the querystring and without any async javascript?

I could just explode the filename once again on `"_"` to get the sort order and store it somewhere, somehow?

This is the code for handeling the page query request:

```
$_SITE_PAGE['qv'] = $_GET['page'];

if (empty($_SITE_PAGE['qv'])){  $_SITE_PAGE['qv'] = explode('-','Home');  }
else {  $_SITE_PAGE['qv'] = explode('-',$_GET['page']);  }

$_SITE_PAGE['file'] = 'pages/'.implode($_SITE_PAGE['qv']).'.pg.php';
```

This code turns "An-Awesome-Page" back into "AnAwesomePage.pg.php" so it's possible to include it with php.

But with a prefix, it's not so easy.

The probliem is; Now there's no way to know what prefix number there was before since it has been stripped away from the query string. So I need to send it somehow along in the "background".

One very bad solution I came up with was to transform the navigation link into a form button and just `_POST` the prefix interger along with the form. At fist it sounded like a nice solution, but then I realized that once a user refreshes their page, it didn't look very good. And after all, that's not what forms are for either...

Any good solutions out there?
Or some other and better way for dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to keep that number saved, you can use cookies or php session variables. 
But in this case, if user first enter the url in the browser or in a new browser, then he should be taken to default number.
Like you have:

```
1_first-page.php
2_first-page.php
3_first-page.php
```

If user enter the url like: domain.com/?page=first-page, you have to take him to 1_first-page.php to any number which you want to be default.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Aatif. Your answer made me realize I would need to somehow make a link between the page name that is queried and the prefix interger. Like in a database. Redirecting a user to a default page isn't an option at all...